# how to use asp.net mvc with those one-page html templates?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm new to web development and I decided to try Asp.Net MVC3.

I purchased this one-page template (http://amatyr4n.com/themeforest/freshlr/#home) to use in my first site but I dont know how to proceed in terms of views.

So my question is:

Should I have a single view or should I separate each page (about, portfolio, services, etc.) into a separate view?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to place most of the common template content in a shared layout file, and the page-specific content in individual views that use the layout file as a base. There's a good basic introduction of the concept on Scott Guthrie's blog here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/22/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts.aspx

**Edited to add:**

Since the template you bought is designed to contain all of the site's static content in one file, then you could get away with one view. If, however, you want to begin adding more pages that work in the same way, you'll eventually want to extract out the common template content into a shared layout as described in Scott's blog post.

Comment: The problem is that the entire template is a single html file. The menu just slides another page when it's clicked. How can I separate this into views since there is only one page load?

Comment: do you know if its possible to separate each menu item into a view and maintain the same sliding efect of the one-page template? nd thanks for the link, I've just finished reading it and solved a lot of doubts I had!

Comment: You would have to modify the javascript that handles the animation, changing it to get the data (probably using ajax) before animating it into the page.